# How to set up a 5ghz hotspot while connected to a 2.4ghz router?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, wifi-configuration

Whenever I select the 5ghz band and try to create a mobile hotspot in Windows 10 I get this error: "The selected network band isn't available".

I have an Intel Dual Band Wireless AC 8265 which as far as I know is capable of both 2.4ghz and 5ghz.

I have tried going into device manager and setting 5ghz as the preferred band, but I get the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can't unfortunately.

Due to regulatory requiremenets (see this [forum post](https://community.intel.com/t5/Wireless/How-to-set-5-GHz-ad-hoc-network-using-a-dual-band-7260-802-11ac/td-p/629793?profile.language=en)), ad-hoc/hotspot modes, aka intentional radiator (IR) modes, are disabled in hardware for the 5  GHz bands on all Intel Dual-Band Wi-Fi cards.

You can therefore only use Intel Wi-Fi cards in the 2.4 GHz bands for hotspot creation.

Comment: Are you sure? Because I'm able to create a 2.4ghz hotspot no problem and I'm positive I've managed to create a 5ghz hotspot while connected to a 2.4ghz (different) router before too.

Comment: @DoingJavascriptForBread 2.4GHz is fine for hotspot creation. 5GHz is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You have one radio that can do both 2.4 GHz and 5 GHz. But not at the same time. A single radio cannot even talk on two channels at the same time. During normal operation (not scanning for networks etc), it is tuned to a single Wi-Fi channel.

Access Points that can do more at the same time have dedicated radios for each band/channel. It is currently popular to have more than one 5 GHz radio on high-end APs/routers.

It doesn’t really matter whether the band is locked. It won’t work either way. Except if you use a different Wi-Fi adapter.